Prime React Menubar not behaving correctly on small screen
Im trying to use MenuBar component from Prime React library, but for some reason, the menubar button that triggers menu bar on small screen does not show, and menubar is showing automatically. this how it looks on my app:

and this is how it should look:

this is my layout/app.tsx:
import { MegaMenu } from "primereact/megamenu";
import MenuStart from "./components/menu-start";
import { useNavigate, useNavigation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHasAccess } from "../hooks/role";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";
import { Menubar } from "primereact/menubar";
interface iProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}
export default function Layout({ children }: iProps) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { hasAccess } = useHasAccess(["ROLE_CHEF"]);
  const items = [];
  NProgress.start();
  if (hasAccess)
    items.push(
      {
        label: "Demandes",
        icon: "pi pi-folder",

        command: () => {
          navigate("/demandes");
        },
      },
      {
        label: "Organizations",
        icon: "pi pi-building",
        command: () => {
          navigate("/organizations");
        },
      }
    );
  useEffect(() => {
    NProgress.done();
  });
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <Menubar start={MenuStart} model={items}/>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}


Btw im using tailwind with prime react,It might be related with the problem so this is my index.css:
@layer tailwind-base, primereact, tailwind-utilities;

/* IMPORTANT: In "styled" mode you must add the PrimeReact Theme here. Do NOT include in "unstyled" mode */
@import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css"
  layer(primereact);

@layer tailwind-base {
  @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}

I want to mention that I tried MegaMenu component and it works perfectly fine, the secend screenshot is from it.
